# asp hiddenfield get empty value from javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to pass value selected parameter in `dropdown-menu` to `hidden-field`. I have traced the code to see `hidden-field` value and it always get empty value.

Also i traced JavaScript code using browser debugger, no errors occurred. whats wrong?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
        $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
    });
});
```

Code-behind

```
protected void btnsearch1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.DataSource = U.Search(hdnSearchParam.Value, txtsearch.Text);
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Markup

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#UserName">UserName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="x" 
                placeholder="Search term...">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnsearch" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                    OnClick="btnsearch1_Click">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSearchParam" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I don't see hidden element `hdnSearchParam`. There is hidden input `search_param` in which case just do `$('#search_param').val(param);`

Comment: i forget to added in code                 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSearchParam"  runat="server" />

Comment: can u try ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680665/i-get-empty-value-from-asp-hidden-field/32685980#32685980

Comment: Your code should work. Does the `hdnSearchParam` have any value assigned to it?

Comment: No it doesn't have any other value assigned to it

Comment: Here's working fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/gogyqb1q/    Can you output the value of hidden field after you assigned `param`: `alert($('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val())` . What do you get?

Comment: it dose not give alert box meaning the code is not  functioning  at all?

Comment: Well, you said no errors in the browser console, right. Are you sure? Put `alert('HELLO')` in the `document.ready` before you bind click. Do you get alert box on page load?

Comment: In place of the line $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param); what do you get if you replace it with alert($('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').length);

Comment: i do not get alert box at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access an ASP.NET control from jQuery/Javascript without making an update to your code.  ASP.NET changes the id of the control at run time.  You have two options:

1. Use the ClientID to get the actual id of the control

   ```
   var hiddenField = $("#<%= hdnSearchParam.ClientID %>");
   ```
2. Set ClientIDMode to static and your jQuery will work as is. 
      (Assuming you're using .NET 4.0 or above)

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSearchParam" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
   ```

More about [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: that is not worked for me in my case i am using asp.net usercontrol

Comment: @HamitYıldırım The OP did not ask about user controls.  I suggest you post a new question.